# What does "start9" do?

Tags: twitch-plays-pokemon

When [TwitchPlaysPokemon](http://www.twitch.tv/twitchplayspokemon) is in Democracy mode, some players are typing commands followed by numbers.

For example, `start9`. It appears that commands followed by numbers are tallied separately in the votes. What is the significance of the number? Would `start9` result in the command `start` if it gets a winning number of votes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

start9 means you're voting for the command start to be used 9 times. It's a quicker version of voting for start by its own 9 different times.